# Reading Oracle data from SAS in a UTF-8 session - characters lose accent

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, sas

SAS 9.4 M6 on a Unix server.  SAS EG 8.1 client.

When reading data in SAS from Oracle (10g release 10.2.0.4.0), special characters like "é", "â" are stripped from their accent so we end up with "e", "a". The result is the same whether we use libname or proc sql pass through.

`libname ken oracle path=u1 SCHEMA=KEN_DEVLP1 user=[user] PASSWORD=[pwd];`

We need to be able to read and view data correctly with both `UTF-8` and `latin9` sessions.

The Oracle database `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is `AL32UTF8` and the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is `AL16UTF16`, obtained from

```
select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET';
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set `NLS_LANG` environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

The `encoding=` Option in your libname statement might fix this.
This is easy to miss, as the keyword `encoding` is neither suggested nor highlighted, as opposed to the other keywords in the `libname`-statement.

Here is how my code looks when accessing a data from a `WLATIN9` encoded oracle database from a `UTF-8` encoded SAS-Session.

```
libname mylib oracle
path     = "mydb.bvch.ch"
schema   = MySchema
user     = MyUser
password = "MyPassword" 
access   = readonly
encoding ='utf8'
;
```